# class instance not printing input argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below class and want to create a create an instance of it and print it's content:

```
from datetime import datetime
class Resultado:

    def __init__(self, jugador, fecha, puntos = 0):
        self.jugador = jugador
        self.fecha = datetime.now()
        self.puntos = puntos

    def imprimir(self):
        return str(self.fecha) + " " + self.jugador + " " + str(self.puntos)


resultado = Resultado("Andrei", 27)
print(resultado.imprimir())
```

But when I run it I get 0 points instead of 27:

```
2020-08-06 12:05:44.978692 Andrei 0
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You have 3 arguments, and you gave only 2.

Comment: Why pass `fecha` if you are only going to use `datetime.now()`?

Comment: So 27 is for `fecha`, which gets overwritten, and `puntos` keeps the default value 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `__init__` method, there are three arguments that you can pass while instantiating an instance of the class. These arguments are:

1. `jugador`,
2. `fecha`,
3. `puntos`.

When you instantiate your object using `resultado = Resultado("Andrei", 27)`, it only provides two arguments. The arguments are passed in the same order as they are defined in the `__init__` method, therefore you have `"Andrei"` in the `jugador` argument and `27` in the `fecha` argument. If you didn't have a a default value of the `puntos` variable defined as 0, it would give you an error. However, you did define the default value, so it gives the argument its default value.

Now, since you don't use the `fecha` argument, you don't actually need it and the definition of your `__init__` method can look like this:

```
    def __init__(self, jugador, puntos = 0):
            self.jugador = jugador
            self.fecha = datetime.now()
            self.puntos = puntos
```

When you instantiate the object now and call your method `imprimir()`, it should give you the result you expect.

Note, that if you want to print your object, you can use the inherited method `__str__` of the Object class. You can do it like this:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.fecha) + " " + self.jugador + " " + str(self.puntos)
```

And then you can just use `print(resultado)` to get the same result.

Also, as of Python 3.6, you can use f-strings, that are easier to work with, so you can write your output as:

```
        return f"{self.fecha} {self.jugador} {self.puntos}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not pass in a value for "puntos" so it is using the default that you provided, which is 0.

I think you do not want "fecha" to be a parameter to **init** since you are not using it.

Call it like this:

```
resultado = Resultado("Andrei", puntos=27)
```